# Add Optional Parameter to Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Suppose I have an Azure Function method definition that looks something like this:

```
    [FunctionName("TestAzureFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("{name}")]Stream fileBlob, string name, MyObject object = null)
```

I want to add an optional parameter to my azure function so other code could also call it. Unfortunately, I get an error saying that this binding is not supported. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the *actual* functionality in a (private) method and call that from two different Functions (or have the method be public and have it be called directly).

In pseudo code:

```cs
// Use bindings here to get the added Blob and its name
[FunctionName("TestAzureFunctionBlob")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("{name}")]Stream fileBlob, string name)
{
    await DoTheMagicAsync(fileBlob, name);
}

// Use bindings here to het the MyObject instance from the post method
[FunctionName("TestAzureFunctionHttp")]
public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]MyObject myObject)
{
    var stream = GetStreamFromHttpRequest();
    var fileName = GetNameFromHttpRequest();

    // Call the generic method
    await DoTheMagicAsync(stream, fileName, object);
}

private void DoTheMagicAsync(Stream stream, string name, MyObject myObject = null)
{
    // Do your (async) magic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have created a function with a blob trigger. If you want to be able to trigger it in other ways than creating a new file in a blob storage you should consider a http trigger or a service bus trigger.